# Trigger an action programmatically

Tags: 8, hooks, actions

I have defined an action and want to trigger it from a hook.

We do **not** want to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, because it is still buggy with Drupal 8. So, we cannot use `rules_invoke_component()`.

What is the correct way to trigger an action? Do I need to construct a new `Action` object? Do I need a service? Is there documentation on that anywhere?

Comment: You must consider using the [Business Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules) module as it is a great alternative to Rules modules and it is quite stable for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
$action = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('action')
  ->load('send_mail');
if ($action) {
  $action->execute($entity);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass $entity in as an array - try

```
$action = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('action')
  ->load('send_mail');
if ($action) {
  $action->execute([$entity]);
}
```

Comment: Without array, it worked perfectly for me. If it works with an array, too, I would find it better to mention this in a comment to the other answer. Having 2 answers with a nearly identical code snippet is confusing.

Comment: Hmmm... Passing a single entity on an 8.9 box gave me a whitescreen.  The [function signature](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21Entity%21Action.php/function/Action%3A%3Aexecute/8.2.x) looks for an array as its only argument, which is then passed to executeMultiple which sticks in a foreach. [