# How can I trigger a Drupal Core action without writing any PHP code?

Tags: 8, actions

On my D8 site I have configured an action of type "Send email" using the Drupal Core "Actions" module (module can be installed under "Administration > Extend"). I want this Drupal Core action to trigger when a new comment is submitted.

In D7 there was another Drupal Core module named "Trigger" which allowed me to configure the desired trigger. In D8 there's no longer a "Trigger" module, nor can I find any other means to configure any Drupal Core action triggers. In the [D8 docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/workflow/workflow-actions-triggers-and-rules) I have found this not-very-helpful paragraph:

> In D7, there are triggers defined, supporting the core Trigger module. This is not supported in D8.

My general question therefore is: How can I configure a D8 site to trigger an action **that was defined via the Drupal Core module "Actions"** when a certain event occurs? Specifically in my case: How can I trigger a "send email" action when a comment is submitted?

As the title of this question mentions, I don't want to write PHP code to achieve this. I am willing to install a stable third-party module, though, **as long as it cooperates with the Drupal Core "Actions" module**.

In a wider sense, I am trying to understand what the Drupal Core "Actions" module does. To me, the module seems to be quite useless if as a site admin I cannot configure triggers for its actions.

Comment: In your specific case the [commment notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_notify) module would be helpful. From description, > Comment Notify is a lightweight tool to send notification e-mails to visitors about new, published comments on pages where they have commented. Comment Notify works for both registered and anonymous users. Otherwise is could be done using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) I think.

Comment: But you know of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), do you?

Comment: @leymannx I've read about it in some other post here on "Drupal Answers", but I ruled (no joke intended) the module out because 1) from what I'm reading on the module page it does not cooperate with Drupal Core actions but defines its own actions & rules & API; and 2) after so many years since the D8 release the D8 port is _still_ in alpha. Did I get 1) wrong? Or in case of 2) is the alpha release actually stable?

Comment: Apparently my question was ambiguous, my apologies for that. I'm looking for an answer that relates to actions that were configured using the Drupal Core "Actions" module. I have edited my question accordingly. Nevertheless, thanks for your answer. I will have a look at the module you suggest if nothing else turns up.

Comment: No, I absolutely think the same. I actually "hate" Rules. `:-#`

Comment: I mean you want Rules without using Rules. The only route is custom code.

Comment: @herzbube Definitely not stable, use with caution (or preferably not at all)

Comment: @Kevin In case you have missed it, let me please point out that I have edited the question to make it (hopefully) unambiguous. I'm asking about the Drupal Core "Actions" module. As a site admin, I wonder how I am supposed to use that module if there is no way how I can configure a trigger. Since you insist on the "Rules" module, let me ask the question: Does that module trigger actions that I configured with the Drupal Core "Actions" module?

Comment: I don't insist on it, I prefer not to use Rules. Trigger was removed from D8 in favor of Rules. But short of using Rules, the only way you will get configurable event/action UI is by using it - or writing code (the way I prefer since its far smaller). See: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246353/trigger-an-action-programmatically

Comment: In this specific case, the smallest amount of code I can imagine is something like hook_comment_insert (or presave, check isNew), if true, call the action as demonstrated in the link provided.

Comment: @Clive Thanks a lot! That clears up everything for me! BTW for follow-up readers, Clive responds to a comment that I deleted. The comment was the following question to Kevin: "You say that _Trigger was removed from D8 in favor of Rules._ This would make sense if Rules supports triggering actions that were configured witht the Drupal Core. Does Rules have this support?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at ECA - event, conditions, actions:
https://www.drupal.org/project/eca

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I no longer use Drupal - always new features while reported bugs never get fixed despite provided patches, and too much hassle updating with every new version and finding out that plugins no longer work.